# Getting selectoption value in method to query

Tags: selectoption

I need to take user name from the select option picklist from vf page and on the basis of that value i need to show tasks related to that user.

i am using below code but unable to get exact reason why i am not getting any value in string username.

below is my code. Thanking in advance for help.

```
<apex:outputLabel value="From:"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <apex:selectList value="{!username}" multiselect="false" size="1" >
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!UserList}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
```

---

```
public with sharing class TaskAssignmentController {
 public String username{get;set;} 

public List<SelectOption> getUserList()
    {
       List<User> ulist = new List<User>();
       getUsers = new List<SelectOption>();
       ulist = [Select id, Name, UserRole.Name, IsActive from User where IsActive=true and UserRole.Name='Caller'];

       if(ulist.size()>0)
         {
       system.debug('this is user list'+ulist);
       getUsers.add(new SelectOption('0001', '--Select--'));
       for(User u: ulist)
         {
            getUsers.add(new SelectOption(u.Id, u.Name));
         }
        }
         return getUsers;
    }

    public string selectedFromUser()
    {
       return username;
    }

    public void setSelectedFromUser(string username)
    {
        this.username = username;
    }
```

and below is the method i m calling on button click to get tasks related to that user

```
 public void showTasks() {

     Set<Id> taskids = new Set<Id>();
     if(wrapTaskList == null) {
        wrapTaskList = new List<wrapTask>();
           }
           try
           {
            System.debug('Inside try');
           User u = [Select Name, id from User where Name=:username LIMIT 1];
           system.debug('this is the selected usr'+u);

               for(Task t: [select Id, OwnerId, Owner.Name, Type, Who.Name, Subject, ActivityDate, Status from Task where Status='Pending' and Subject=:taskType
               and ActivityDate>=:duedate and ActivityDate<=:enddate and Owner.Name=:username limit 50]) {
                  taskids.add(t.id);
                  System.debug('Inside for loop');
                wrapTaskList.add(new wrapTask(t));

                if(wrapTaskList.size()>0)
                showtable = true;
                {
                   System.debug('Inside if');
                   system.debug('List of tasks'+wrapTaskList);
                }
              }

              countTask = [Select count() from Task where id in: taskids];
              System.debug('this is count of task'+countTask);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
              System.debug('##Exception occured'+e.getMessage());
              if(wrapTaskList.size()==0)
              ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO,'No task found!'));
            }

    }
```

I always get No task found! message

Please provide me the guidance required.
I know its easy and i m missing on small detail.

Comment: Basically, you're hiding an exception. Check your debug logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up the user's Name and Id.

```
   <apex:selectList value="{!username}" multiselect="false" size="1" >
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!UserList}"/>
    </apex:selectList>
```

Here, your select list's selected item is bound to the variable `username`.

But your `SelectOptions` have the user's name as their label, and the user's Id as their value. It's the select option value that is placed in the bound variable.

```
        getUsers.add(new SelectOption(u.Id, u.Name));
```

When you query for users

```
       User u = [Select Name, id from User where Name=:username LIMIT 1];
```

you treat the variable `username` as if it contains a user name, but it actually contains a user Id. Change the `WHERE` clause to look for Id, and it should return a result. You should also check, however, that a value other than your `--select--` choice has been chosen.

At present, it's throwing a `QueryException` that your `try`/`catch` block then eats.